# Cartopy installation on Mac OS: Python 3.8 and Matplotlib 3.3.3

Tags: cartopy, proj

Matplotlib [basemap](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/download.html) is deprecated in favor of [Cartopy](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/) - however, it seems that to install cartopy only the Anaconda package manager can handle dependencies. I am following the instructions to [install via pip](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/installing.html#installing) as it seems I had an old version of [proj](https://proj.org/install.html). But it fails to brew the installation to run with Python 3.8 and Matplotlib 3.3.3. Anyone using this set up? Or is it better to downgrade? Which versions are stable? Or shall one stick to Anaconda?

The error I get is 'proj_api.h' file not found, same as [this one](https://github.com/petere/pex/issues/8), for another tool. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40719116/making-proj-api-h-available-for-pip-install-cartopy) does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to `proj<=8` as suggested [here](https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/1140) worked out. I already had brewed `proj`, and the other dependencies not handles by `pip`, thus the steps I took are

```
brew uninstall proj
brew install proj@7
```

Then adopted the suggestions from brew to make sure compiler and pip can find `proj`, then run `pip install cartopy`